# No list of internal splits provided! No Rules URL Provided?

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am setting up GATE to run on a text document, I want to use DefaultTokenizer and POSTagger, but I am getting error while initializing ANNIE controller.

Exception in thread "main" gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: No URL provided for the rules!
    at gate.creole.tokeniser.SimpleTokeniser.init(SimpleTokeniser.java:131)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:302)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:117)
    at gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser.init(DefaultTokeniser.java:55)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:302)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:97)

Can you please help?

Comment: Did you set up the GATE home correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with its home, so I just removed old version, reinstalled GATE latest version and set path accordingly and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share information how you created application pipeline?

From the error description I can assume that you have a wrong path in your Tokenizer. May be you accidentally added something to default path.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ProcessingResource tokeniser = (ProcessingResource) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser",Factory.newFeatureMap());
    SerialAnalyserController pipeline = (SerialAnalyserController) Factory.createResource("gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController");
    pipeline.add(tokeniser);
```

Comment: Could you please at least provide a comment about the error in the question and why your answer should fix it.